# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'searchCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get ui-router to work and I'm getting pretty close. Well I got it working, but I can't combine it with my controller, then I'm getting errors.

I'm getting this error in the console

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'searchCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

searchCtrl.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp')

  .controller('searchCtrl', [

    '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.search = function() {

        var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
        var service = '/search/movie';
        var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
        var search = $scope.searchquery
        var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
        var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

        $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            if (status == 200) {
              $scope.movieList = data.results;
              console.log($scope.movieList)
            } else {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
            }

          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          });
      }

    }
]);
```

My searchModule.js

```
var app = angular.module('movieseat', ['ui.router']).config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
    return $stateProvider.state('state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      templateUrl: 'assets/angular-app/templates/state1.html'
    });
  }

]);
```

And my app.js.coffee

```
@app    = angular.module('movieseat', []);
@myApp  = angular.module('myApp',[]);

# for compatibility with Rails CSRF protection

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
])

@app.run(->
  console.log 'angular app running'
)
```

[This might be the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und) and I've tried adding another module to my app.js.coffee but it's not working.

Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Do you want to create two different modules here? If answer is yes then inject myApp module into movieseat. Here which module you are binding with template?

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I don't think I want 2 modules. The `searchCtrl.js` is a controller which alowes users to make a search action. And the `searchModule` is a module which includes a template. So maybe I'm wrong in declaring a module in the `searchCtrl.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change first two module declaration line of your **app.js.coffee** like below.

```
@myApp  = angular.module('myApp',[]);    
@app    = angular.module('movieseat', ['myApp','ui.router']);
```

and then in **searchModule.js**

```
angular.module('movieseat').config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
    return $stateProvider.state('state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      templateUrl: 'assets/angular-app/templates/state1.html'
    });
  }

]);
```

**REASON :** Here you are basically overriding the module you previously created insted you just need to use that already declared module.

If you are doing with single module then

```
@app    = angular.module('movieseat', ['myApp','ui.router']);

# for compatibility with Rails CSRF protection

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
])

@app.run(->
  console.log 'angular app running'
)
```

and

```
angular.module('movieseat').config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
    return $stateProvider.state('state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      templateUrl: 'assets/angular-app/templates/state1.html'
    });
  }

]);
```

and your controller looks like

```
angular.module('movieseat')

  .controller('searchCtrl', [

    '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.search = function() {

        var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
        var service = '/search/movie';
        var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
        var search = $scope.searchquery
        var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
        var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

        $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            if (status == 200) {
              $scope.movieList = data.results;
              console.log($scope.movieList)
            } else {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
            }

          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          });
      }

    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Clear explanation. But I'm going to have to do some more research in the whole controller/module part because the difference isn't totally clear.

Comment: Cool, Happy to help you. Let me know if you find any difficulties in understanding this. !!

Comment: I sure will, doing the https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ tutorial now, so I'm guessing it wont be long before I'm stuck again ;).