# when page loads why chrome console shows the error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my `module`

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);
```

here is my controller in the different js file

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', function ($scope, customersaveService) {
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.IsFormValid = false;
    $scope.ButtonText = 'Save';
    $scope.submitted = false;
});
```

`_Layout.cshtml` has ng-app set up on the `<html ng-app="myModule"></html>`

but when i call this from the view

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<form name="f1" ng-submit="SaveCustomer(data)" novalidate>
    <span style="color:red">{{message}}</span>
    First name:
    <input  type="text" name="txtFirstName" ng-model="User.FirstName" ng-class="submitted?ng-dirty:''"  required autofocus />
    <span ng-class="error" ng-show="((f1.txtFirstName.$dirty || submitted) && f1.txtFirstName.$error.required)">Please enter a first name</span>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value={{buttontext}} />
</form>
</div>
```

when the page loads the chrome console shows the error '`myController`' is not a valid function. i could not think of any reason why this throws this error?

**here is the error:**

> angular.js:13236 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myController' is not a
>   function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=myController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at angular.js:68
>       at assertArg (angular.js:1825)
>       at assertArgFn (angular.js:1835)
>       at angular.js:9831
>       at setupControllers (angular.js:8852)
>       at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8898)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8226)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8229)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8229)
>       at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8106)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236 http://localhost:26210/favicon.ico Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You should use `myModule.controller("myController",function(){});` or `angular.module('myModule',["ngRoute"]).controller`

Comment: @Amit but angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', function(){}) is the same thing

Comment: you have to give dependencies using `angular.module('myModule',["ngRoute"]).controller`

Comment: do u inject dependencies ?

Comment: @Amit angular.module(myModule) should call the existing module and i dont want to recreate another module

Comment: @Amit i have used this before without the 'ngROute' but it worked thsi does not work here çus this is a form submit?

Comment: @hadiJZ there is a service call but it has nothing to do with it, it says the myController is not a function

Comment: I test ur sample in stack snippet it work correctly.

Comment: @hadiJZ that cannot be let me close the browser and rerun it

Comment: @hadiJZ same error and i have updated with the error in the orginal post

Comment: can u make a plunker

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und

Comment: @Amit here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/9DkeAntXWuzOtyOikpHR

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
myModule.controller('myController', [ "$scope","customersaveService", function ($scope, customersaveService) {
  $scope.message = '';
  $scope.IsFormValid = false;
  $scope.ButtonText = 'Save';
  $scope.submitted = false;
}]);
```