# Is Grunt's Uglify breaking my Angularjs code?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify

So, I'm new on Grunt and I'm making an small app to test the watch, concat, uglify and cssmin plugins.

I'm concatenating my JS code and uglifying the concated file. But I'm getting a "Error: [ng:areq]" on my console. If I call my JS files individually without using uglify and concat, it works fine.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ezSeguros">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gestión de Seguros</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/styles.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="InputController as nameCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-change="nameCtrl.showName(name)" ng-model="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="build/js/scripts.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular
    .module('ezSeguros',[]);
```

**controller.js**

```
function showCtrl() {
    this.showName = function(name){
        console.log(name);
    }
}

angular
    .module('ezSeguros',[])
    .controller('InputController',[showCtrl]);
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports= function(grunt){

    // Project configuration. 
    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['app/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:js','uglify'],
            },
            css: {
                files: ['assets/css/custom/**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['concat:css','cssmin'],
            },
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                banner: '(function () {',
                separator: '})(); (function () {',
                footer: '})();'
            },
            js: {
                src: ['assets/js/**/*.js','app/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'build/js/scripts.js',
            },
            css: {
                src: ['assets/css/custom/**/*.css'],
                dest: 'build/css/styles.css',
            },
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            },
            scripts: {
                files: {
                    'build/js/scripts.min.js': ['build/js/scripts.js']
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'build/css/styles.min.css': ['build/css/styles.css']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','uglify','cssmin','watch']);

};
```

And this is the error itself:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=InputController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Thanks!

Comment: that's one reason why `grunt-ng-annotate` is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grunt isn't the issue here. You're bootstrapping a new Angular module twice.

Example:

```
angular
  .module('ezSeguros') // Your new angular module is already defined in app.js
  .controller('InputController',[showCtrl]);
```

See also:

Angular modules: [Angularjs: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und)

Angular minification best practices: [Angularjs minify best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)