# How to create bar chart using progress bar in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to create a bar chart using progress bar in AngularJS for my below value.

**My response will be :**

```
var json_response =  {

  "data": [
    {
      "standard": "Ist",
      "max_students": 20,
      "available_students": 8
    },
    {
      "standard": "IInd",
      "max_students": 15,
      "available_students": 10
    },
    {
      "standard": "IIIrd",
      "max_students": 50,
      "available_students": 22
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to use above response and display it in a form of vertical bar chart.

Comment: angularjs has nothing to do with charts specifically,  consider using third party tools like c3.js, highcharts, etc..

Comment: If i use html to create progress bar chart using value from angular function. Then ?

Comment: then it only going to cost you a lot of efforts, you need to write lot of javascript code and css unnecessarily

Answer (score 1):

If you just want progress bars you can use [`ui-bootstrap` progressbar](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar)

Here's a fiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/pritojs/uub4tw7d/3/

Answer (score 0):

You want to check [Angular-ChartJS](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) out. It gives you a lot of options to create your charts using angular directives.

You could do something like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = [];
  var students_data = [];
  var available_students_data = [];

  angular.forEach(json_response["data"], function(data) {
    $scope.labels.push(data["standard"]);
    students_data.push(data["max_students"]);
    available_students_data.push(data["available_students"]);
  });

  $scope.series = ['max_students', 'available_students'];
  $scope.data = [students_data, available_students_data];
});
```

And in your html you just have this :

```
<div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
  <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"> chart-series="series"
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKZH5l0OIv1ZwgooQyIx)

Comment: If i use html to create progress bar chart using value from angular function. Then ?

Comment: @KalaiyarasiM, I updated the answer. Check the plunker to see if it is close to want you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am getting version angularjs 1.2.20 and in above it is using angular 1.4. So I am getting error while i mention ["chart.js"].

Comment: " Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'BarController' is not a function, got undefined "

Comment: @KalaiyarasiM, I am not sure if angularjs version is going to be a problem with Angular-ChartJS because It has been tested on 1.2.x. The error you are getting shows that you are probably declaring your angular module wrongly. Check this  stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25895387/4092170